# Canvas Instrucuture Arc API

Tags: media-library, canvas-lms

For the courses we have in Canvas Instrucutre, the media files are in Arc Media Library. But the API to access these media files isn't available.

Is there a way to access the Arc Media files from Canvas API?

Comment: Arc media is not accessible using the Canvas LMS API. Arc has its own API that you can use to access your media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ARC media API is available in https://"your-canvas".instructuremedia.com .

The documentation is available at https://canvas.instructuremedia.com/api/docs